# How to reload listview on a activity?

Tags: android

I have 2 activity.
In activity 1, i have a `listview` show data from database and button `Insert` 
Activity 2 use to add something to database. 
When I click button `ADD` in activity 2, i call method `finish()` and return to activity 1.
So, somebody can show me how to reload `listview` in activity 1 please?

Comment: can you show a piece of your code

Comment: use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  method of adapter

Comment: can you post some code

Answer (score 1):

Recreating the adapter should help, because you need to get a new dataset as Kaaaarll said.

So for example you have something like this in your code:

```
MyData data = database.getData();
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
ListView list = new ListView();
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and in the next run, in the onResume(), get fresh data and reapply the adapter:

```
MyData data = database.getData();
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: after adding new data to list(data) you can also call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

You can re-query the database to get the latest data and then repopulate your listview's adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Notify the dataset in the `onResume()` method activity 1. It should be something like `listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Don't forget to check whether they are `null` or not.

Let me know if it worked.

EDIT:

Something like this should do the work (in activity 1):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (listViewAdapter != null) {
        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```